# Retornar determinado valores de um array

Tags: javascript

Consumo uma Api cujo retorno é um array com **10** objetos dentro, quero mostrar na tela apenas os cinco primeiros do array, que são sempre os mais recentes na Api, como podem ver no código abaixo, no teste com o **while** consegui pegar 5, mas, somente os 5 últimos, tentei tbm dar um **`reverse()`** antes do 
**length**, porém, bugou mais ainda a lista:

```js
let api = [
  {
    "id": 44,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Filtro de data cartão virtual ",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Testes mais testes",
    "institutionName": "0721 30** **** 7893",
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferi 100,00 reais",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 4895",
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transf. de 350 reais",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferência de Duzentão",
    "institutionName": "0221 30** **** 0114",
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "fdfdfd",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 0843",
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferindo 400",
    "institutionName": "0721 30** **** 7893",
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Teste 200",
    "institutionName": "0321 20** **** 1995",
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "recarga 100",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Primeira Recarga",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 0843",
  }
]

let i = 5;

while(i < api.length) {
  console.log(api[i]);
  i++;
}
```

Como posso pegar apenas os cinco primeiros resultados do array, e guardá-los se possível em um array, pois, estou utilizando em uma tabela com Angular e faço um **ngFor**.

Comment: tente mudar o let i = 5; pra let i = 0; e o while(i < api.length) para while(i < 5)

Comment: @Sumback, poste uma resposta, é bom para ficar registrado no site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o método `splice`, passando por parâmetro a posição de inicio e fim para atribuir as 5 primeiras posições em um novo array;
Ai em seu `ngFor` utilize o array criado para iteração.

```js
let api = [
  {
    "id": 44,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Filtro de data cartão virtual ",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Testes mais testes",
    "institutionName": "0721 30** **** 7893",
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferi 100,00 reais",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 4895",
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transf. de 350 reais",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferência de Duzentão",
    "institutionName": "0221 30** **** 0114",
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "fdfdfd",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 0843",
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferindo 400",
    "institutionName": "0721 30** **** 7893",
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Teste 200",
    "institutionName": "0321 20** **** 1995",
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "recarga 100",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Primeira Recarga",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 0843",
  }
]

let arr = api.splice(0,5);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar o `.slice(0, 5)` que te dá exatamente os primeiros 5. Ou seja cria uma nova array só com uma parte da array inicial.

A API do `.slice` é `.slice(<indice onde começar>, <indice onde acabar>)`.

```js
let api = [{
    "id": 44,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Filtro de data cartão virtual ",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Testes mais testes",
    "institutionName": "0721 30** **** 7893",
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferi 100,00 reais",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 4895",
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transf. de 350 reais",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferência de Duzentão",
    "institutionName": "0221 30** **** 0114",
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "fdfdfd",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 0843",
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Transferindo 400",
    "institutionName": "0721 30** **** 7893",
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Teste 200",
    "institutionName": "0321 20** **** 1995",
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "recarga 100",
    "institutionName": "0021 30** **** 7404",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "owner": null,
    "ownerName": null,
    "bankAccountId": "e8b2eb06-0df8-43bb-8012-ea42b63fb91f",
    "description": "Primeira Recarga",
    "institutionName": "0221 20** **** 0843",
  }
]

const primeiros5 = api.slice(0, 5);

console.log(primeiros5);
```